# Search URL redirect problem

Tags: pagination, search

I'm having a strange problem with my search results page when i search i get this in the URL http://f.cl.ly/items/2Z1c1b2G1n0B3r3W063B/Screen%20Shot%202011-09-29%20at%201.21.19%20PM.png "see the X & Y" ? i don't know where do they came from & i can't seem to figure how to fix it & it breaks my pagination, so how can i fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an image button for your submit. It sends the x and y coordinates of where the button was clicked as well as any other get parameters. I would recommend using a standard submit button and then use CSS to replace it with an image. Alternatively if you don't know CSS a button tag with an image inside it should work eg:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="search-button.png" alt="search" /></button>
```

Comment: I'm using <input type="image" /> not a <button>

Comment: Actually using a <button> with an image inside it fixed it

Comment: @gabri I know it wasn't a <button> you were using initially. What I meant was if you use <input type="image" /> it will send the X & Y corodinates of where you clicked on the image input as GET parameters.